# Why don't lightsabers affect water?

Tags: star-wars, tv, lightsaber, the-clone-wars

In the 1st and 2nd episodes of the currently running season 4 of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, there were many underwater scenes ınvolvıng lightsabers. If you've watched those episodes, you'd have noticed that there wasn't any effect on water around the lightsabers.

From my point of understanding, lightsaber blades are thousands of degrees Celsius. That's why they could cut metal sheets.
And, with such high temperature, lightsabers could break down water molecules as well as vaporize them (distant molecules), which could create a whirlpool of powerful water currents around it. But nothing happened. Why?

Am I mistaken about temperature? Can the temperature of a lightsaber be controlled using the Force? What's your canonical explanation of this?

Comment: Are the Clone Wars cartoons considered canon?

Comment: @JackBNimble - Unfortunately, yes. Extremely unfortunately so, they are [T-canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon#The_Holocron) - meaning, only 1 step below movies and HIGHER canon than EU books. The only thing more depressing is Midichlorians

Comment: This question reminded me of [a moment in Ryan vs Dorkman 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RATMJ8JH1qo#t=104s) where Ryan is dragging his lightsaber through a puddle, and you can clearly see the steam coming off as the water is vaporizing. So at least their version of lightsabers do affect water.

Comment: @DVK: You mean Jar-Jar depresses you less than T-Level canon and midichlorians?  That's scary!

Comment: @TangoOversway - meesa really don't see why people hate Jar Jar so much. Bink wasn't the highlight of the movies, but I don't have any significant objections to him as a character and appreciate him as CGI. Just think of him as a product of cross-breeding of C3PO and Ewok.

Comment: It would appear that canon levels vary based on how much money lucas makes off of them.  I suspect that if a book were ever to earn more than the tv show some exception for the canon level would be made for it.

Answer (score 14):

Interesting.

The [Wookieepedia Lightsaber article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber) states:

> Water: All lightsabers, unless specially made, would short out when they were submerged in water, due to rapid chain reactions and the instant overpowering of water on the blade. In rain, a lightsaber would steam up, but not short out.

The sources for that statement are:

- Clone Wars chapter 5 (makes sense - the episode takes place on Mon Calamari)
- Clone Wars chapter 19

Also, from Wikia for [Kit Fisto](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kit_Fisto) (the Jedi on Mon Calamari in Chapter 5)

> **Fisto's lightsaber contained two crystals employing a bifurcating cyclical-ignition pulse that allowed the blade to operate underwater.** This proved helpful on Mon Calamari during the Clone Wars (unsourced)

The above piece is unsourced and to be honest sounds like a typical WikiaLucasy technomumbojumbo, but hey....

Comment: Of course, they did prepare for underwater battle, so they'd have made their lightsaber water-proof. But, I am asking different thing: why didn't it affect water?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - No canon info I could find. I'm left with the unsatisfactory "LucasPhysicis".

Comment: If I had to make an uneducated guess, either the plasma was somehow majicked (bifurcating cyclical-ignition pulse) to not interact with water molecules, or there was some special water-resistant force field around it (the latter presents problems as far as cutting through flesh underwater)

Comment: Water is dipolar so should be repelled by the magnetic field....

Comment: @Pureferret - Umm.. Shouldn't that just be that it's aligned by the mag field?  One side pulled.. one side pushed.. that being why water doesn't normally respond to magnets.. (but the alignment being why it expands when frozen.)

Comment: @KeithHWeston If you have a strong enough magnetic field water is [repelled by it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iygf2qy5LqI). Considering these things contain plasma, I'd say the fields are strong enough.

Comment: It's not a very divergent field, it's tightly confined about the plasma blade.

Comment: @Pureferret Great.. It can also be added to question..

Comment: Well, in the Young Jedi Knights series, Luke, Jacen, Jaina, and a few others used their lightsabers to cut ice while underwater on Mon Calamari. Anja Galladro (I think I misspelled that) also helped, and she was using a very old lightsaber she found somewhere. So maybe some were designed that way and some were not?

Comment: Ha, "Mon Calamari" :')

Answer (score 6):

Water exhibits very weak diamagnetism, and thus under extreme fields, such as those confining a lightsaber blade, **the water should be repelled**. The repelling effect keeps the hot blade from the water. The same cannot be said about the handle and the electronics within, unfortunately.

**As the water is repelled, the heat of the blade should have no effect on the water as the blade never touches the water.**

Comment: How is it answer?

Comment: humans are 90% water... lightsabers should not be able to harm humans.

Comment: If you have two sacs of water bound together and you try to insert a hot magnetic field in between them would rip them apart from the field, and burn the sac. That's what's happening to the cells in the human body when a lightsabre slices through it like a hot knife through butter.

Comment: Heat transfer isn't limited to touch.

Comment: No it's not, but the convection and radiation I am assuming to minimal.

Comment: -1 The field serves to keep the plasma in not to keep anything out.  That is how it cuts using the plasma blade that allows matter in but keeps the plasma from escaping.

Comment: @Chad Plasma is matter. Water is Diamagnetic and would be repelled. Other matter will be paramagnetic attacting the blade. These effects probably won't be that great, but I think it might solve the lightsabre underwater issue without effecting general use of one in combat.

Comment: @Pureferret it would have a repellant force however there is the force of gravity and the force of the water above, and below(the displacement) the blade acting against it.  You can force magnets together against the force repelling.  The repellant effect would not be in play until inside the blade anyway since the plasma is contained.

Comment: @Chad If you want I can get my pen and paper out and *calculate* the field strength needed to counteract the inward displacement force of the water, but I assure you it won't be unimaginably high.

Comment: @Pureferret Chad is correct. As magnetic field is constant, its can't auto-adjust against variable water pressure. No matter how much you exert magnetic field (in considerable amount), water wouldn't be push away due to weak diamagnetism of water & enormous pressure of whole water world.

Comment: @SachinShekhar my point is that the field required to contain enough plasma to function as a lightsabre should  hold the water out.

Answer (score -1):

Compared to the huge, cool water mass, one lightsaber is not a big source of heat. The water touching the blade would certainly vaporise but the surrounding water would in turn cool the steam almost instantly. In effect, you might get a shell of water steam around your blade, and the surrounding water might warm gradually. Warmer water goes up, but that would be almost invisible even in reality, so not showing it in an animated series is fair.

We should get a physicist to calculate the numbers.

Comment: You need to re-calibrate your physics, man.

Comment: Even below boiling temperature, you can find bubbles in water. Lightsabers are big things to deal if water wants to ignore heat fully..

Comment: @Raphael Water molecules are broken down at approx 500 degree Celsius (Sachin has mentioned it in question, but not with exact temperature). So, there would be bubble of hydrogen and oxygen molecules too.

Comment: @MikePeterson ... which the lightsaber would immediately ignite again. Interesting.

Comment: @Mike Exactly!!

Comment: @Raphael If you're interested with real physics, this should be happened: Extreme heat will break near-by water molecules & this hot air will pass heat to distant molecules to vaporize them. This will create a huge pressure difference to trap cool water molecules. Water from top try to come below with equal speed, but air from middle will push them up to equalize pressure. It creates vertex to create whirlpool. Due to this whirlpool, same level water will join its flow to make whirlpool bigger and powerful.

Comment: Can you guys give a reference for this? Wikipedia does not give any temperature of importance of around 500 degrees C. I also don't the effect @SachinShekhar mentions; where can I read on this?

Comment: @Raphael The effect I mentioned in question is called `Thermolysis`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermolysis . And, Mike is wrong with 500 degree Celsius. Its 2000 degree Celsius for pure water. I didn't mention temperature because it varies based on impurities.

Comment: @Raphael More diet to your curious mind: Oxy-Acetylene cutter torch operates between 3200 to 3500 degrees C. As lightsabers cut faster, its safe to assume its temperature higher than 3500 which is greater than 2000 (to do Thermolysis).

Comment: @SachinShekhar That explains that water breaks apart (which I never doubted even if I, admittedly, did not think of it when typing my answer) but not the other drastical effects you mention.

Comment: @Raphael I have already explained that for vertical lightsaber in rest. It not 100% correct to say exact whirlpool due to motion of lightsabers, but for sure... it will disturb few miles of surrounding water body because lightsaber will always give heat for process continuity. Its fluid dynamics!

Comment: You've gone very far. No need of advanced fluid dynamics and thermolysis here when Mr. Lucas didn't show even bubbles originating from lightsaber which is point of question.

Comment: having seen much cooler underwater welding, the bubbles of steam rise faster than they can cool.