# Can Laser Weapons Work Under Water?

Tags: star-wars, tv, the-clone-wars, mobile-suit-gundam

**Can a laser or laser beam travel through water?** I saw a battle scene in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, season 4, episodes 1 and 2 where they are exchanging laser blasters. Though I don't know anything about their lasers or what is special about that particular laser, I want to believe that it could work underwater, especially since it scatters when it bounces against crystals. Water is like thousands of crystals, if I may make a comparison.

Yet, in that same episode they used light sabers, that can heat up very quickly when they come into contact with anything. **Shouldn't the water boil when it comes in contact with the light saber if that's the case?**

Backing up to the idea that Lasers can't work underwater. In Gundam SEED, they can't use laser swords or laser blasters underwater, so they use a combat knife or a bazooka instead.

Comment: Technically [Blasters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Blaster#Blaster_mechanics) aren't laser weapons, but are instead particle weapons. `Instead of a coherent beam of light, the blaster fired a compressed, focused, high-energy particle-beam that is very destructive, commonly referred to as a "bolt".`  I am not sure what effect this would have on using it underwater.

Comment: The weapons in all Gundam series are plasma type, none are lasers in any way.

Comment: For lightsaber based discussions, go to this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10557/why-dont-lightsabers-affect-water

Comment: great answers. but im looking for some kinda futuristic physics way. even without reference. those formulas made my left brain bleed. lol

Comment: Suggest this question be migrated to [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: why physics. i was looking for star wars physics / space

Comment: LOL LOTS Of edit happened to this question. My original question was lost. nevermind

Comment: I agree with @Wikis, this sounds like it was intended as a real-life physics question, and belongs over there...

Comment: @Wikis If the question is about *real* lasers it could find a home on Physics.SE. If the OP is interested in answers appropriate to one or more science fictional universes then it has no place on physics as we have a strict rule against "fictional physics". (Physics.SE mod)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Medium always influences the performance of a weapon but that's not a given - weapon designers can change the design to balance the strengths and weaknesses in a different way. Mind that you can never design the "perfect" weapon because there is always a trade off. Unfortunately, most authors aren't aware of this delicate balance or time constraints make it impossible to do it. So most weapons in SciFi movies and books simply don't make sense or are utterly unbalanced.

For Star Wars, [blasters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Blaster) are used but it's not really clear what a "blaster" is other than that it can be set to different power levels dealing damange that ranges from "stun" to heavy explosions.

They do have some characteristics of a plasma weapon but they aren't. Plasma has a strong urge to disperse, so you would need something to keep it together (focused) and that something has to go with the plasma. [There are plasma configurations which are self-stabilizing](http://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/energy/nuclear/plasma-ring-experiment-offers-new-path-for-fusion-power) but we'll have to see what their limits are.

Also the amount of energy you can put into a plasma has an upper limit. In fact, it's way more simple to build a more powerful laser weapon but real lasers work completely different than what you can see in any movie. With the amount of power available to a Star Wars battle cruiser, you could easily build a multi-megawatt laser. That laser could cut through anything - other ships, moons, planets - in a reasonable amount of time and there would be no defense against it.

Shields couldn't stop it because the laser brings all it's energy into a very small place, so the whole surface of the shield must be able to withstand that amount in every spot. You could try to build a shield that can be "concentrated" but then I come with two lasers. If you could power such a shield, it would be a waste because you could use the same energy to power hundreds of lasers that simply blast any enemy out of the sky *before* they can fire on you making shield useless.

That would be disastrous to the story: All battles would be over in a few seconds. Whoever gets to fire first wins. No heroic deeds. Worse, battles would be fought over distances of 100'000km up so the enemy would be nothing but a blinking dot on a radar. If you looked out of a battle ship, you'd see nothing but black space. No camera angle would be able to catch the action.

So the whole discussion is about a technology that we don't understand and that the inventors never understood, either. It's a means to create tension as the story progresses, nothing more. Physics and logic as we understand it has to take a second seat behind suspense and the demands of the story.

Comment: A mirror designed for the correct frequency would reflect the laser beam, but of course a tunable or multifrequency laser can easily defeat one. Lasers of course don't work well under water or in an atmosphere, as the matter would absorb and disperse the beam (rl lasers do suffer from this, it limits their range and limits the choice of frequencies for them so as to minimise the effect, one reason the ABL as so large it required a B747 to carry it was the extra power needed to compensate for atmospheric dispersion/blooming).

Comment: I did some research on this. The best laser type for atmosphere is a UV laser, it can pass through thousands of kilometers of air without losing much power. Just like UV light from the sun. And just like UV light, it would burn the skin of *every* living thing that has a direct line of sight to almost any point on the line of fire. So when fired from orbit, it would kill every living thing on the same side of the planet. As Sarah Connor put it: "Anyone without a Sunblock below 10'000'000 will have a really shitty day."

Comment: It loses power, Aaron, because it loses focus. The energy gets dispersed as it is scattered. That's why such high power is needed for long distance shots, to ensure that at the aim point there's still a high enough energy density to heat the target to where damage ensues (in contrast to popular belief, laser weapons don't cause things to blow up or melt directly, they cause fuel and especially fuel vapour to overheat and ignite, possibly after burning a small hole). That same high power of course means that you get collateral damage over a large area, which is what Connor refers to.

Comment: I know that you [can't focus all the energy in a single spot](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13648/physics-of-focusing-a-laser) and that it gets dispersed (the answer below gives all the gory details). As a weapon, a UV laser beats all other laser types when you want to slag ground targets from an orbit in terms of cost, efficiency and technology level.

Comment: With regard to not being able to contain plasma: That is wrong. You can create plasma that produces its own magnetic field to contain itself - just extrapolate this experiment: http://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/energy/nuclear/plasma-ring-experiment-offers-new-path-for-fusion-power

Comment: @flq: Thanks, improved my answer.

Answer (score 23):

Light scattering is a relatively complicated process.

In short, the beam will get wider and lose power, making it work less well.

Both of these reduce the *intensity*. If you like, think of intensity as pressure, as both intensity and pressure are *inversely related* to area. That is to say if two beams have the same *power* but one has a wider spread and thus *larger area*, that laser will do less 'damage'. In the same way, a bullet which hits with the same force but has a larger cross section will do less damage.

Now on to **Scattering**:

Unfortunately water is not really like crystals, which diffracts light into patterns. Water and most liquids are what we call amorphous. Here is a picture of Water (amorphous) on the left and Ice (crystalline) on the right:

[image]

Basically the atoms in an amorphous liquid cause the light to bounce every which way, very little lines up and it gets scattered.

The main process that occurs in light scattering is **Mie Scattering**, but a decent approximation is **Rayleigh Scattering**.

[image]

Ignore **everything** there except the second bracket.

- In Rayleigh Scattering, the attenuation (loss of power) is proportional to the inverse of the wavelength (lambda, which looks like an upside down Y) to the *power of 4*! That's right, have a short wavelength and the attentuation *shoots* up. If we double the wavelength we increase the attenuation by a factor of *16*, if we triple it it goes up by a factor of *81*!

That's all well and good, but what does it looks like? Well that depends on the size of the particles in the water. Unless the water is completely clear lots more scattering takes place.

Here is a comparison of scattering in clear water, and milky water.
[image]

It enters from the right, get's scattered in the murky liquid then passes straight through the clear water. The pattern on the far left has a much bigger area around it where the light has spread out.

Here is another one where we can see how the light is spread out in the 'turbid' fluid, and it doesn't go that far. This is the *widening* and the *loss of power* I talked about at the start.

[image]

To understand how the different wavelengths interact with water and other particles, here is some data:

[image]

You can see, major scattering occurs from the particles in the water but not the water itself (other factors do play into it, and the difference between air and water does matter over long distances in water).

I would liken this scattering effect to turning the laser rifle into a much weaker *sawn off laser shotgun*. Not as powerful but with more spread.

In short: yes it will work, just not as well.

[Edit: as requested from wikipedia:

[image]

Absorption plays a much greater role in clear water, and is dependant on what vibrational modes the EM wave excites in the molecule. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water) for more of an explanation. **TL;DR** if it's anything but visible light it's going to struggle to pass more than a few cm through the water.

Comment: Blasters don't fire electromagnetic waves, so the answer is meaningless.

Comment: I know, but the question is still "Can Laser Weapons Work Under Water?" The examples given aren't lasers but I'm still trying to answer the question.

Comment: @bitmask don't thank me, thank physics!

Comment: @Pureferret: I have an ambivalent relation to physics. I love it for its beauty and sometimes hate it for struggling with understanding it.

Comment: @Pureferret - Nicely illustrated, but you didn't actually explain why scattering and not water absorption is the primary problem.  The question was not about using lasers in _muddy_ water.

Comment: @RexKerr You've already covered absorption well enough. I mainly know about scattering and not a great deal about absorption. Looking it up, a lot is still not known about water absorption, but I did find a pretty graph.

Comment: @Pureferret - That graph is all you need to understand it, though!  It's far simpler than scattering, actually.  transmittance = e^(-absorption coefficient * distance); absorbance = 1 - transmittance.

Comment: @Pureferret I thought given sufficient power levels a laser (or other high energy ---weapon--- beam) could ionize the atmosphere and allow a higher impact, essentially creating a scatter free "tunnel".  Wouldn't it be able to do the same thing by vaporizing water (albeit at some power loss)?

Comment: @C.Ross You'd need a 28kW laser to boil a 50 metre long .5mm diametre cylinder, plus the energy to split the molecule and ionise it. To split that amount of water you'd need roughly 1000 kJ, plus another 1.737 GJ to fully ionise the water, to only partially ionise it only needs another 5000kJ. We're looking at ~6*10^6-1.8*10^9 joules (the upper bound is slightly more than your average lightning bolt) to create a tunnel, if such a tunnel would be scatter free, I'm not even sure. Nor if it could even be set up due to initial scattering.

Comment: There is a version of the abosorbtion graph in Jackson's book on *Classical Electromagnetism* that covers many more decades of wavelength which is absolutely fascinating.

Answer (score 7):

Laser weapons can work through water but *not very well*.  The reason is that, as you suggest, the light will be absorbed by the water as well as the target, which will boil the water and cause all sorts of other problems.

Pure water has an absorption coefficient of about 2*10<sup>-2</sup>/m, which means that the bulk of the power will be absorbed after traveling 50m through water--and that's if the laser is the optimal wavelength (blue-green).  Turbid water or other colors will considerably shorten this distance.  So underwater, a laser is at best a short-distance weapon.

Laser swords don't actually exist, so it's less clear how they would interact with water.  Presumably they would boil the water, making them rather interesting to use, but depending on the postulated physics of the device, various other things could potentially happen.  For example, anything using magnetic containment wouldn't work underwater because of the relatively high conductivity of water.

Various particle weapons would go through water little better than they would go through a wall; there are about the same number of atoms there to collide with.  Anything that shoots "bolts" typically is supposed to be some sort of particle weapon (e.g. magnetically-confined plasma).

Comment: I think actually lasers would be very poor underwater, as they would boil the water, making it bubble, and so further disrupt the laser light. It might work to boil your enemy, but as even a close combat weapon, I feel it would be tricky to handle.

Comment: What shown in Season 4 Episode 1,2 was blaster. And, blasters don't fire electromagnetic waves, so there's no point of `absorption coefficient`…

Comment: @SachinShekhar - The question asked about "laser weapons", so that's what I devoted the bulk of my answer to.  Blasters are not lasers, and hence I added something on "particle weapons" (which blasters are).

Comment: @SchroedingersCat - You can impart energy to your target instead of the water at a rate proportional to the total absorbance of the target divided by the absorbance of the water. If your target is only a meter away or so, that could put the vast majority of the energy into the target (so the water wouldn't boil, but the target would be heated by ~1000 degrees C). You could come up for a simple bound on total energy delivered in the beam at a given diameter to avoid boiling (in clear water). In turbid water, it could be arbitrarily bad (e.g. if you can't see the target, neither can the laser).

Comment: @rex - I suppose if you are in clear water, it might work, but if you are in combat with someone the chanced of the water being clear are low. So yes, I agree, they may work for stealth close weapons. But I think the predictability would become a limiting factor. Even 1M away in cloudy or churned water might be too much. And if someoe is trying to kill me with a laser, the water will be very churched up....

Comment: @SchroedingersCat - You won't be firing lasers at someone you can't see.  The chance that you'll be tempted to use a laser against someone in murky water is pretty low.  Granted, after you shoot a few people and there's a bunch of blood in the water, you may end up boiling the bloody water instead of hitting your target.  I guess the trick is to kill them before it gets to that stage.  (Bleeding should be limited by cauterization....)

Answer (score 1):

According to books signed in to star wars canon by George Lucas himself, prior to his redefining this canon with the advent of his Clone Wars cartoon, blasters and light sabers would short out when they came into contact with bodies of water. Drops such as rain and splashing had no effect other than sizzling. (lightsabers and lasers burn hot, not just bright.) According the books, contact with the water created a sort of feedback loop that would short out the lightsabers and blasters. (if blasters were under water, that is.) 
That being said, I'm sure that there were blasters that could have been modified in some way to work under water. There were no instances, however, of lightsabers working underwater until the advent of that season of Clone Wars.

George Lucas changed many things for this cartoon that were already considered canon, through books that were authorised by him. My conclusion is that he simply didn't read any of the material that he called canon, and didn't listen to his fans when they revealed that these things contradicted each other.

One solid example of lightsabers shorting out can be found throughout the Jedi Apprentice series.

Comment: The Clone Wars TV series was signed off on by Lucas for approval to be created, but he had no active part in the creation of any of the stories or episodes. He is only an executive producer. The show is considered T-Canon, and so the movies/novelizations of them still supersede anything from the Clone Wars show.

Answer (score -1):

Laser can go in water medium as it can go in air medium. The one and only condition is that the given medium must not absorb the laser light. If a medium is not absorbing laser light its temperature will not increase or it will not boil.

Comment: bogus, and self contradictory.

Comment: It's not laser, it's plasma.